# Google Adwords API authentication with OAuth2 in Python with suds

Tags: python, soap, oauth-2.0, suds, google-ads-api

I'm trying to get to grips with Adwords API with OAuth2 authorisation.

I can authorise an account to get an authorisation code.  I can exchange this code for an OAuth2 access_token/refresh_token.  But what next ...?

The Google Adwords API SOAP request headers require authToken, developerToken, and userAgent (with clientCustomerId being optional).  Can anyone point me towards documentation that goes from access_token to authToken (I presume that's the element I'm missing).

I'm working in Python, and have successfully used the Python Adwords library, as well as using suds as the SOAP client to call the API directly, using username/password to create the authToken, but I need to move to the OAuth2 implementation for my app.

I've searched on the interwebs, in the Google Adwords Group, and here on StackOverflow, but haven't found anything to help.  I've looked at the OAuth2 playground but haven't managed to get that to do any of the SOAP related calls yet, though that's my next point of call.

Any help or suggestions would be most appreciated.

Cheers
H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-python/wiki/AdWordsOAuth2

it should point you in the correct direction.  It just seems Google puts the previous version up front (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ads-python/wiki/AdWordsOAuth).  That page should definitely be marked as deprecated and point to the new one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The AdWords API doesn't actually support oAuth 2.o yet, so that's probably your problem; it currently only supports 1.0a. The python example code can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-python-lib/source/browse/trunk/examples/adspygoogle/adwords/other/use_oauth.py

Comment: The example that you link to appears to be using oAuth 2.0. Nevertheless, I do face the same problem as described by Howard Sandford.

Comment: The example's probably been modified since I originally posted this since the AdWords API has now been updated to support oAuth 2.0. In fact oAuth 2.0 is now the recommended authentication mechanism, and you should also note that oAuth 1.0a and the ClientLogin API have been depreciated, so you should go with oAuth 2.0 if possible.

Comment: The example has not been modified, and it confusingly loads python-oauth2, which seems like the second iteration of the python implementation for OAuth 1.0 protocol.. as the latest http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-python-lib/source/browse/trunk/adspygoogle/common/oauth/PythonOAuth2OAuthHandler.py file explicitly states oauth version 1.0a, even though .py file has 20 inside.  So basically, Python does *not* have OAuth 2.0 support anywhere I can see.